# Django imagefield.save NoneType is not subscriptable

Tags: django, django-models

I'm making a model called Image that has a method to save another version of itself with a different size. But I can't get the ImageField in the new version to accept the saved image file. It fails on the save method, with 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable.

```
def newversion(self, size):
    """ Save a new version of the image """

    image_version = Image(user=self.user, original=self)
    image_version.save()

    path, old_name = os.path.split(self.image.path)
    ext = os.path.splitext(old_name)[1]
    vsn_name = "{0}{1}".format(str(image_version.id),ext)
    vsn_path = os.path.join(path, vsn_name)

    pil_image = PIL.Image.open(self.image.path)

    if pil_image.mode not in ('L','RGB'):
        pil_image = pil_image.convert('RGB')

    pil_image.thumbnail(size, PIL.Image.ANTIALIAS)
    pil_image.save(vsn_path, pil_image.format)

    image_version.image.save(vsn_name,ImageFile(open(vsn_path)), True)
```

Answer (score 1):

It is because I am on Windows, and I need to open the file with "rb":

```
open(vsn_path, 'rb')
```